# Wrong score in elastic search result

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Not getting the correct score for the elastic search query result.

ES Query -

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(emergency) OR (emergency*) OR (*emergency) OR (*emergency*)",
            "fields": [
              "MDMGlobalData.Name1"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

ES result -

```
{
  "took": 29,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 798,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 9.169065,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551037160",
        "_score": 9.169065,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "PARAGON EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551040507",
        "_score": 9.169065,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY MD"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551076447",
        "_score": 9.169065,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "COASTAL EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551100746",
        "_score": 9.169065,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY MD"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551090880",
        "_score": 9.169065,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "PAFFORD EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551106787",
        "_score": 9.169065,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "CAPROCK EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551021568",
        "_score": 9.121077,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "WILTON EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551124137",
        "_score": 9.121077,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY ONE"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551125549",
        "_score": 9.121077,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY ONE"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customermasterdata",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MDMCM551133066",
        "_score": 9.121077,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY MD"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ideally, The first set in the result should be the Name1 which has value just "emergency" or start with the word "emergency"

And how could we have the same score for almost first 5 result sets? Being the Name1 value is different.

Due to wrong scoring, the results are messed up.
How to correct the score in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, That need not be the case. Because ES follows [Lucene scoring function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html)

Reason for the same score:

1. You have only two terms in each document - `emergency and one more word`
2. `Emergency` word matches as it is. [Field Length is same](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#field-norm)
3. Number of occurrence is one. i.e [Term frequencies are same](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#tf).
4. Relevancy is same for all the terms. [idf](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#idf)
5. [Coord](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#coord) is same as your doc contains only one occurrence of `Emergency`

But if you have a document with `Emergency X Y Z`, then score of this will be lower than the other documents which you have. Because `term frequency` is higher for this one.

And if you have only `Emergency`, score of this document will be higher than all.

It is perfectly normal to have same score in your scenario as user doesn't know which `emergency` he/she meant.

**Update:**

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":{
                "term":{
                "MDMGlobalData.Name1":"emergency"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the sample data, output:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "emerge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "iN1hKnMBojxRtp6HNI7d",
        "_score": 0.10938574,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "emerge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "g91TKnMBojxRtp6Hto4q",
        "_score": 0.08701137,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "PARAGON EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "emerge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "hN1TKnMBojxRtp6H2I6A",
        "_score": 0.08701137,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY MD"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "emerge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "hd1TKnMBojxRtp6H_I6_",
        "_score": 0.08701137,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "COASTAL EMERGENCY"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "emerge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "h91VKnMBojxRtp6HYI4e",
        "_score": 0.07223585,
        "_source": {
          "MDMGlobalData": {
            "Name1": "EMERGENCY MD X"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: got it @Gibbs. How to make search result to bring Name1 set which has value just "emergency" or start with the word "emergency"?

Comment: but still the result is not matching our requirement. we want exact match first, then, keyword starts with and the keyword ends with, then the rest of the results. Like - EMERGENCY, EMERGENCY MD, ... ,PARAGON EMERGENCY, ... ,MD EMERGENCY WAY, ... @gibbs

Comment: Hope you misunderstood. Only emergency ll come first. The two words out of one is emergency. Then three words out of one is emergency. Like this.

Comment: To confirm, it is not possible to have result set in the way I mentioned? @gibbs

Comment: No, not possible I believe. I am not sure whether you can achieve this by custom scoring.